# Mesh Hit With RayCast

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting

I was detecting distance from one defined point to the surface of an object with;

```
private float GetDist2()
{

    float distance = 0.0f;


    Ray ray = new(transform.position, -Vector3.up);
    Debug.DrawLine(transform.position, Vector3.down, Color.red);

    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out RaycastHit hit))
    {
        if (hit.collider.CompareTag("world"))
        { 
            distance = hit.distance;
        }
    }
      

    return distance;

}
```

But there is a problem with that, it return distance considering the object a cube I think. But my object has uneven surface with slops etc. So returning distances are not correct.

I want to measure distance from given point with transform.position  to surface (mesh normals ?) the object in that case it is the "world".

Comment: What kind of collider is on your mesh object?

Comment: Good question it is Box collider.

Comment: So yes, in that case it will respond as if it's a cube. You would want to change that out to a MeshCollider and given the shape you describe, make sure `convex` is false.

Comment: I think I can do what I want to do after try to use mesh collider. However I added two empties to the object which is moving and made one the starting point and the other target to make ray sync with moving object. I used this trick in in in Apple's Scene Kit before.